# How do I livestream the video I have captured using OpenCV on my webpage which is made using Django while also keeping the face recognition function

Tags: python, django, opencv, face-recognition, live-streaming

I am a new developer working at an interI am developing a web application which takes your attendance using face recognition and puts the entry in the database using django, python, open-cv and the face_recognition library of python. The Login page looks like this: [Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGr7C.png).

When I click the login button, my views program directs to an external python function which opens a separate camera window which does the face recognition. [The Camera Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nywu6.png).

What I want to do is display the camera directly in the browser window rather than as a separate window. I found some tutorials and also tried to implement them but using them I can only display the frames in the browser window while the functionality of face recognition is lost.

The Views Code (views.py):

```
def camera_on(request):
  out = Popen('E:/Study/Internship/Capstone/Project/Web App/web_app/Basic.py', shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
  op = out.stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
  new_str = ''
  for i in range(len(op)-2):
      new_str += op[i]
  request.session['name'] = new_str
  return render(request, 'open_camera.html', {'data': new_str})
```

This code accesses the Basics.py file which opens the camera window, does the face recognition and gives the entry in the database.

The Basics.py code:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'web_app.settings')
django.setup()

import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
from opencamera.models import Logs
import pymysql

conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='projectdb')
cur=conn.cursor()

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cur.execute('SELECT Name, Photo FROM employee')
result=cur.fetchall()

known_face_names=[]
known_face_encodings=[]

for i in range(len(result)):
    known_face_names.append(result[i][0])


for i in range(len(result)):
    img = face_recognition.load_image_file(result[i][1])
    img_encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
    known_face_encodings.append(img_encode)


face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
process_this_frame = True

while process_this_frame < 15:
    nam = "N/A"
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()    
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

    if process_this_frame:
        
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            name1 = "N/A"

            
            face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name1 = known_face_names[best_match_index]
                nam=str(name1)

            face_names.append(name1)
   
    
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name1 in zip(face_locations, face_names):
    
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left - 10, top - 50), (right + 10, bottom + 50), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left - 10, bottom + 30), (right + 10, bottom + 50), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name1, (left + 10, bottom + 45), font, 0.5, (0,0,0), 1)

    cv2.imshow('Attendance Cam', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    
    if nam != "N/A":
        process_this_frame += 1
        if process_this_frame == 13:
            print(nam)
            today = date.today()
            now = datetime.now()
            now=now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            sql = "SELECT Action FROM logs WHERE Name=%s"
            recs = (nam)
            cur.execute(sql, recs)
            status = cur.fetchall()
            stat = ''
            if len(status) !=0:
                length = len(status) - 1
                stat = status[length][0]
            
            if stat == 'Exit' or len(status) == 0:
                attd = 'INSERT INTO logs (Name, Action, Date, Time) VALUES (%s, "Entry", %s, %s)'
                rec = (nam, today, now)
                cur.execute(attd, rec)

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code opens the camera, puts a green box around your face if its in the database and then makes an entry in the logs if recognized.

I need help integrating this functionality in the live stream in the browser window.

Comment: do you want to show the _server's_ camera or the user's camera who uses the browser?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I think I want to use the Server's Camera because I dont know if I can run the pyhon script for the face recognition on the userls camera. Can I?